# Arithmetic term doesn't fail but its negation does

Tags: prolog

given the query `?- p == 'p'.`, prolog outputs `true`.
But given the query `p =\= 'p'.`, prolog outputs

```
ERROR: Arithmetic: `p' is not a function
ERROR: In:
```

Why is that? whats the difference between `==` and `=/=` so p is somehow evaluated differently?

Comment: `==/2` checks if two terms are equivalent. `=\=/2` is an *arithmetic expression* comparison operator, but `==/2` is not. `=\=/2` is really the negation of `=:=/2` which checks if two arithmetic expressions evaluate to the same value. So `=\=/2` attempts to evaluate each argument and checks if they are not equal. So attempts to evaluate `p` and `'p'`, but these are not known Prolog arithmetic functions. For more details, see the online documentation for [`==/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D%3D/2) and [`=\=/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%5C%3D)/2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negation of `==` is not `=\=`, but `\==`.

From [comparision operators](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Ebillw/dictionaries/prolog/comparison.html):

> `T1 == T2` succeeds if terms `T1` and `T2` are identical
>
> `T1 \== T2` succeeds if terms `T1` and `T2` are not identical
>
> `E1 =:= E2` succeeds if values of expressions `E1` and `E2` are equal
>
> `E1 =\= E2` succeeds if values of expressions `E1` and `E2` are not equal

`=\=` expects `p` and `'p'` to be expressions and attempts to evaluate, but they are not.